# Building VS2017 docker proj on Windows1709 errors 'Docker server host is configured for 'Windows'

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I have a TeamCity build server with an agent installed in a Windows Server 1709 (Windows Server 2016 build 1709) with docker with Linux support installed.

However when the build tries to run, it is giving me error "Docker server host is configured for 'Windows', however the docker-compose project targets 'Linux'".

In this version of Windows, I don't have to switch back and forth between Linux and Windows mode. If I am remembering correctly, it defaults to Linux mode and you specify Windows mode using command line switches.

How can I get around this error?

This is a project that I've been working on in Visual Studio. Server and workstations are both running VS2017 15.7.1 and Docker project is upgraded to 2.1

Comment: I don't want to mark this as the answer b/c I'm having other issues that could be tricking me into thinking this is resolved, but I think I fixed this by installing docker-compose.exe. docker compose doesn't get installed when you install docker on Windows 1709 and causes some weird errors when trying to build with Visual Studio etc.

Comment: If anyone is interested in what other issues I'm having, my current blocking issue is that the docker on Windows 1709, after building an image, cannot push it to an Azure Docker Registry.